# Как лучше исправить "соревнования среди исторических занятий региона"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, падежи

> Роли в пьесе передаются по наследству. Для поддержания формы и
>   тщательного соблюдения традиции жители содержат музыкальную школу,
>   школу барабанщиков, кружок балетного и бального танца. Проводят
>   **соревнования среди исторических занятий региона**: стрельба из лука,
>   верховая езда, фехтование, **уроки знаменосцев**, актёрского   мастерства, кройки и шитья  – и так далее и тому подобное.

"Уроки знаменосцев" потянули за собой родительный падеж, а стрельба-езда-фехтование остались в именительном...

Ничего или чего?

---

---

P. S. Спецдополнение для тех, кому "не хватает контекста".

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> Тот день 1494 года почитается здесь как памятный день, считают что это
>   день победы Любви и Чести. С тех пор проводят театрализованный
>   шахматный турнир, разыгрывая ту самую судьбоносную партию вновь и
>   вновь. Веками. Поколениями. Прерывались лишь на время войн начала ХХ
>   века. Однако все это впереди. Пока перед ним рекламная пауза –
>   заставка нового художественного проекта от Йоко Оно.
>
> 27./57. Глашатый. Шахматы. Сценография Мирко Вучетича. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 27а./58 Лучники на крепости города Маростика. Шахматы. Сценография
>   Мирко Вучетича. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> И вот на шахматной доске, на которой вот-вот начнется игра, появляются
>   шути и глашатые. Они выкрикивают начало. Отряды лучников стреляют
>   горящими стрелами со стен города и очерчивают квадрат огня вокруг
>   знаменосцев. Барабанная дробь.
>
> 28./60 Знаменосцы. За кулисами. Шахматы. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 28а./59 За кулисами. Шахматы. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 28б/61 Пешки отправляются на игру. За кулисами.Шахматы. Маростика.
>   2106 г.
>
> В то время за кулисами – за крепостной стеной города, разминаются
>   многочисленные артисты. Это местные жители, горожане, хвастают перед
>   нами своими навыками, которые сохранили с XV века. Игра в шахматы
>   перебивается несколькими интермедиями, в том числе серди прочих,
>   выходами знаменосцев – они делают удивительные трюки с флагами. С
>   резким рёвом разрезают они ритм барабанов. Хлещут полотнищами, как
>   хлыстами. Но вот скоро в игру вступят пешки. Младшие фигуры уже
>   направляются в сторону сцены.
>
> 29./62 Интерлюдия. Шахматы. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 29а./64 Шахматная партия. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 29б./65 положить лого Шахматная партия. Вид с трибуны. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> Пока вниманию представлена одна из интерлюдий – выступление местной
>   балетной школы. Трогательный танец юных танцовщиц призван передать
>   волнения лирической героини – красавицы Лионоры. Сможет ли
>   полюбившейся ей юноша превзойти соперника в столь сложной игре?
>
> И вот расставлены фигуры и партия в разгаре! Есть что-то
>   завораживающие в том, что шахматные ходы свершают люди. И даже конь
>   самый настоящий. Жаль, не печатают на пригласительных билетах
>   шахматную композицию. С нами были заинтересованные лица. Ребята хоть и
>   юные десяти и шести лет, но спорт они этот любят. И даже на каких-то
>   турнирах места берут. Им бы очень пригодилось! Ну очень все были
>   взволнованы происходящим, чтобы уследить за логикой партии.
>
> 30./67 Шествие. Шахматы. Сценография Мирко Вучетича. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 30а./69 Финал. Шахматы. Сценография Мирко Вучетича. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> 30б/66 Конное шествие. Шахматы. Сценография Мирко Вучетича. Маростика.
>   2016 г.
>
> Старомодная, но тем и прекрасная работа художников по свету. Без
>   лишних спецэффектов. Картинка под открытым небом живет, мягко
>   переливается в ясном лунном свете. Особенно впечатляет невероятное
>   количество дисциплинированной и красивой массовки, точнее актеров в
>   костюмах XV века. В эти дни их на площади чуть меньше чем зрителей.
>
> Этот праздник – честь горожан. Роли в пьесе передаются по наследству.
>   Участники регулярно репетируют. Для поддержания формы и воспитания
>   традиции, жители содержат музыкальную школу, школу барабанщиков,
>   кружок балетного и бального танца. Проводят соревнованиях среди
>   исторических занятий региона: стрельба из лука, верховая езда,
>   фехтование, уроки знаменосцев, актерского мастерства, кройки и шитья,
>   и так далее и тому подобное. Всем городом дружат – поддерживают между
>   собой неформальные связи.
>
> 31./68 Шахматы. Партия. Сценография Мирко Вучетича. Маростика. 2016 г.
>
> Игра окончена. Лионора, которая наблюдала за партией из окна своей
>   башни, зажигает свет. Она подает знак служанке, но он понятен и всем
>   горожанам на площади: победитель – Вьери её избранник! По этому знаку
>   начинается кульминация празднества – всеобщее ликование, салют над
>   крепостью города и даже огненный дождь по стенам. В местных барах этой
>   ночью гуляет стар и млад. Шестнадцатый век мешается с двадцать первым,
>   вино с граппой. А совсем под утро остается немного старой-доброй
>   итальянской эстрады, под гитару.

Comment: Может, так: "проводят соревнования по исторически традиционным занятиям в регионе: стрельбе из лука, ..."?

Comment: Спасибо! Будем думать!

Comment: Я не могу расшифровать, как связаны "соревнования" с "уроками знаменосцев". Это "кто лучше проведёт урок для знаменосцев"? Или всё же речь о "навыках/мастерстве знаменосцев"?

Comment: Речь о пьесе, которую ставят из века в век. Всё перечисленное после двоеточия как раз состоит из исторических, традицией закреплённых занятий.

Comment: Нечего им тянуть падеж. А нельзя просто покороче: *Выбирают лучших в стрельбе из лука...*?

Comment: Переписывать надо всю фразу по ее убогости и кривости, ну и да, начать с "соревнования по...". Галина, вам нужен настоящий **литредактор** с классическим русским языком(вижу не первый раз потребность) - и за деньги, а не мысли детей

Comment: Дорогой Лази! Я сама не просто литредактор, я редактор широкого профиля. И сюда я обращаюсь, когда мне нужно прокрутить варианты, что-то отшлифовать, потому что автор мне в этом не помощник. Но нельзя же объять необъятное! Ну не бывала я в ресторанах со звёздами Мишлен! Главное, что требуется от профессионала, спохватиться: а вот этого я не знаю! а вот в этом я не уверена... "Мысли детей" мне очень помогают.

Comment: Комментарий всем. Я дополнила свой текст неправленым, зато сильно расширенным контекстом, из которого видно, что такое сырой материал и какой из меня спозиционированный редактор.

Comment: *P. S. Спецдополнение для тех, кому "не хватает контекста".* - Спасибо. Так это ж другое дело. Ясно. У меня мозги в эту сторону бы не повернулись. Ну в пеовом приближении - #2 в моем ответе остается как базовый, но только упростить его. Соображу - напишу.

Comment: Что такое сырой материал - это не критично знать, а вот контекст - да, совершенно неожиданный. Во-первых то, что это некий гид, а во-вторых, то что это и впрямь какая-то анимация-самодеятельнеость, но европейского разлива. Ну и то, что тут все увязано, а не просто набор всяких разных действий...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вариант:

Роли в пьесе передаются по наследству. Для поддержания формы и тщательного соблюдения традиции жители содержат музыкальную школу, школу барабанщиков и знаменосцев, кружок балетного и бального танца. Проводят состязания в разных видах исторических воинских доблестей (стрельба из лука, верховая езда, фехтование), организуют уроки (*или занятия*) актёрского мастерства, кройки и шитья и так далее и тому подобное.

Логично барабанщиков и знаменосцев объединить.

Comment: Комментарий всем. Я дополнила свой текст неправленым, зато сильно расширенным контекстом, из которого видно, что такое сырой материал и какой из меня спозиционированный редактор.

Answer (score 1):

Контекста не хватает. Править надо, но сильно зависит от смысла.

Тут варианты:

-1. Это среди тех, кто продолжает заниматься этими вещами (ну типа "лучший по профессии")

***Проводят соревнования по профессии среди занятых традиционными занятиями жителей региона (стрельба из лука, верховая езда, фехтование), уроки знаменосцев, актёрского мастерства, кройки и шитья – и так далее и тому подобное.***

Перечисление после двоеточия корректно, но уж очень глаз режет слитностью двух разных перечислений.

-2. Просто в качестве такой анимации заставляют людей исторической фигней страдать

***Проводят соревнования по традиционным занятиям жителей региона (стрельба из лука, верховая езда, фехтование), уроки знаменосцев, актёрского мастерства, кройки и шитья – и так далее и тому подобное.***

-3. Соревнования спортивные

***Проводят соревнования по традиционным видам спорта (стрельба из лука, верховая езда, фехтование), уроки знаменосцев, актёрского мастерства, кройки и шитья – и так далее и тому подобное.***

Ну и так далее, реально без контекста не скажешь...

> "Уроки знаменосцев" потянули за собой родительный падеж, а
>   стрельба-езда-фехтование остались в именительном...

А это и не важно, это два **разных** ряда однородных членов-перечислений, так что тут даже хорошо, что падежи разные, хоть как-то можно смысл понять. Но скобки все одно лучше.

Пожалуй что вариант №2 самый правдоподобный, но на все 100 не поручусь. Такой текст убойный, любая подлянка может выскочить.

Comment: Впишусь, что "вариант №2 самый правдоподобный" - и читаемый без крови из глаз

Comment: @LazyBadger  - меня сильно смущает фехтование как традиционное занятие. Где-то в Ближней Азии, кажется, было такое, что фехтованию (на ножах, что ли) учили всех. Но в европейских реалиях это занятие было только для весьма благородных. С другой стороны, традиционные занятия - термин применим в основном к малым народностям и прочим аборигенами мест на обочинах цивилизации. Поэтому остаётся только догадываться, что тут имел в виду автор.

Comment: @LazyBadger Кстати, я согласен с замечанием Галине, что тут нужен специалист. Галина не в первый раз ставит меня в тупик, позиционируя себя редактором с большим стажем. Но я нашел для себя, что лучше не заострять на этом внимание, отвечать на её вопросы по сути, как ответил бы на экзамене или, наоборот, экзаменуя по РКИ. Всё больше толку даже для сторонних читателей.

Comment: Комментарий всем. Я дополнила свой текст неправленым, зато сильно расширенным контекстом, из которого видно, что такое сырой материал и какой из меня спозиционированный редактор.

Answer (score 0):

**В качестве вступления**

Форма теста должна, прежде всего,  **просто и доходчиво передавать его содержание,** то есть он должен легко читаться и без труда пониматься. С другой стороны,   текст **не должен быть примитивным,** его  жанр может допускать  какие-то художественно-изобразительные приемы, чтобы книга была эмоциональной, дополнительно воздействовал на чувства читателя. Две эти задачи должны решаться и при этом не мешать друг другу.

Что можно сказать об этом отрывке. Я его читаю долго, но понять не могу. Здесь уже не до красоты стиля, просто неясно, о чем речь.

**В качестве варианта от читателя** (как он понял текст, но без гарантии, что он понял его  правильно):

Роли в пьесе передаются по наследству. Для поддержания формы и тщательного соблюдения традиции жители содержат музыкальную школу, школу барабанщиков и знаменосцев, кружки балетного и бального танцев. Проводят соревнования в разных видах  исторических занятий региона: стрельба из лука, верховая езда, фехтование, актёрское мастерство, кройка и шитьё – и тому подобное.

Comment: Комментарий всем. Я дополнила свой текст неправленым, зато сильно расширенным контекстом, из которого видно, что такое сырой материал и какой из меня спозиционированный редактор.